# Parsing JSON with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a probem when I parse file like this all works

{"StumbleUpon":0,"Reddit":0,"Facebook":{"total_count":19227,"comment_count":0,"share_count":19227},"LinkedIn":27}

my code:

```
module SocialShares
  class Sharedcount < Base
    def shares!
      response = RestClient.get(url)
      JSON.parse(response)['Facebook']["share_count"] || 0
    end

  private

    def url
      "https://free.sharedcount.com/?url=#{checked_url}&apikey=#{Rails.application.secrets.socialshared_api_key}"
    end
  end
end
```

And when I parse this i have error TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

file:
{"StumbleUpon":0,"Reddit":0,"Facebook":0,"LinkedIn":0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second structure doesn't have the necessary structure to navigate it that way. You need to approach this more cautiously:

```
def shares!
  response = RestClient.get(url)

  data = JSON.parse(response)

  data['Facebook'].is_a?(Hash) && data['Facebook']["share_count"] || 0
end
```

You can also do this in Ruby 2.4 or later:

```
  data.dig('Facebook', 'share_count').to_i
```

Comment: Can you use the `dig` method? Your data structure is highly inconsistent and it's difficult to use. I've upated the code to make it even more paranoid.